# Can't get ng-cloak to work

Tags: angularjs, ngcloak

I have a custom directive where I present the values in it using {{}} but the problem is when the page is reloading I get to see {{}} there before setting the values. I tried using ng-cloak but too bad it is not working for me. After googling this I found an article stating that the problem might be timing: that angular takes time to use ng-cloak when loading large contents. Is this right? Do I have to change anything in my settings? Is there a value I should pass to ng-cloak?

Here's my custom directive

```
<button ng-click="myCtrl.clicked()" ng-hide="myCtrl.conditionOne" ng-disabled="myCtrl.conditionTwo" class="{{myCtrl.class}}" ng-cloak>
    {{myCtrl.value}}
</button>
```

Comment: Please include the code that's causing problems.  It's very hard to tell what the problem is without it.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I just added my code

Comment: Did you add the corresponding CSS-rules?

Comment: Yes I did! didn't work! Could it be the timing issue I read about?

Comment: Are you loading your JavaScript at the top or bottom of your index.html? If you let Angular add the ng-cloak styles then you need to load it at the top (head) of your index.html. Otherwise you can explicitly include the CSS rule as @Sean3z describes.

Comment: bottom, in the body.

Comment: I used javascript. on HTML, display:none and after my AngularJS assets are loaded, $(".[relevantClass]").css("display","block");

Answer (score 2):

Typically, when [`ng-cloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) "isn't working" it's due to not having the accompanying CSS:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried this and didn't work! Could it be the timing issue I read about?

Answer (score 1):

Straight from [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak):

> For the best result, the angular.js script must be loaded in the head section of the html document; alternatively, the css rule above must be included in the external stylesheet of the application.

And that optional rule is:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak { 
    display: none !important; 
}
```